# import qs is undefined, but works with require

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, google-cloud-functions

I have a code that runs on NodeJS 14 on Google Cloud Functions, I am using *typescript* with `tsc` to compile my code.

```js
import qs from 'qs'

console.log(`qs >>> ${qs})
```

The code above logs (in production)

> qs >>> undefined

I think the problem is my `tsconfig`, could someone help to check if there is some something non usual on my configuration?

If I use `require('qs')` the code works.

My `tsconfig.json`:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "outDir": "lib",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "strict": true,
    "target": "es2017",
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true
  },
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "include": ["src", "tests"]
}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try it with:

```
import * as qs from 'qs'
```

Comment: Why I can't use `import qs from 'qs'`?

Comment: Because you are importing a CommonJS module. Checkout [this](https://itnext.io/great-import-schism-typescript-confusion-around-imports-explained-d512fc6769c2) :)

Answer (score -1):

To specify external dependencies for Cloud Functions you have to follow these guidelines, which ask you to [include the dependencies you need in your package.json](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/specifying-dependencies-nodejs#including_local_nodejs_modules) file and once that is done, to load them, you have to [use require()](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/specifying-dependencies-nodejs#loading_nodejs_modules).

[This](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/specifying-dependencies-nodejs) is the correct approach provided in the official GCP documentation for Cloud Functions using the NodeJS runtime. I believe you are following these steps from the results you're obtaining, but I fail to see why would you have to use `import qs from 'qs'` other than for using Typescript syntax specifically.

If the require() approach works for you, being this approach the one provided in the documentation, I suggest you to follow this procedure instead.